# HTML 5 - Facebook comments custom css

Tags: css, facebook

How to add custom CSS to the HTML 5 [Facebook comments](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) plugin?

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=123456789";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://example.com" data-num-posts="2" data-width="470"></div>
```

Thanks. Uli

Comment: Even if you find a way to change that, you should realise that is against Facebook policy. You have no rights to change FB comments, Like button etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following to your css code:

```
.fb_iframe_widget, .fb_iframe_widget span, .fb_iframe_widget span iframe[style] {
width: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#fb-comments { 
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    color: #ff6600; 
}

#comments a { color: #ff6600; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I have found no way to do this. The content is loaded into an iframe via javascript. If it was injected directly into the DOM it would be possible, but wouldn't auto-update.

Answer (score -2):

Inspect resulting HTML with Firebug or WebKit inspector, and create according CSS.

Comment: Why is this wrong? Can't you overwrite Facebook plugin CSS with your own? And you can do that inspecting with Firebug to know which CSS selectors use.

Comment: FB Social plugins are in their own Iframe, so the css on the 'parent' website doesnt apply